# Checking Mobile Network connectivity in android

Tags: android, android-networking

how to check whether network is connected or not in android mobile phone..(network means not internet connection or data connection its simple mobile network like AIRTEL, CELLONE,VODAFONE etc..)

I tried with ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE and  ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI but they are used for checking data connectivity... and not network connectivity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009804/check-network-connection-android

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TelephonyManager's getSimOperator()`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Activity activity) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity == null)
    {
        return false;
    } else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) 
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

you should add this permission to manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: He wrote "network means not internet connection or data connection " . He's not asking about internet connection. Just simple connection to the network, meaning he can make calls and receive them

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

**getSimOperator()**

> Returns the MCC+MNC (mobile country code + mobile network code) of the provider of the SIM.

e.g. to Get operator ID( MNC+MCC) from SIM Card

```
 public String getOperator()
       {
            TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) mGap.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String operatorName = manager.getSimOperator();
            return operatorName; 
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public class ConnectionDetector {
    private static Context _context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
        this._context = context;
    }

    public static boolean isConnectingToInternet(){ boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)_context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;}

}
```

add these permissions in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: But he wrote "network means not internet connection or data connection " . He's not asking about internet connection. Just simple connection to the network, meaning he can make calls and receive them

Answer (score 0):

In order to check the status, there are 2 ways:

1. ServiceState constants : STATE_EMERGENCY_ONLY, STATE_IN_SERVICE, STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE, STATE_POWER_OFF .

Those you get by calling `telephonyManager.serviceState.state`.
If you wish to listen to changes you use PhoneStateListener by calling `telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE)` . To unregister you call `telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE)`

This is a good solution because it seems that even if you don't have a SIM card, you can still sometimes (in some countries) call emergency phone numbers, such as the police.

```
enum class PhoneServiceState {
    STATE_EMERGENCY_ONLY, STATE_IN_SERVICE, STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE, STATE_POWER_OFF, UNKNOWN;

    companion object {
        fun getFromValue(value: Int): PhoneServiceState = when (value) {
            ServiceState.STATE_EMERGENCY_ONLY -> STATE_EMERGENCY_ONLY
            ServiceState.STATE_IN_SERVICE -> STATE_IN_SERVICE
            ServiceState.STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE -> STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE
            ServiceState.STATE_POWER_OFF -> STATE_POWER_OFF
            else -> UNKNOWN
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
PhoneServiceState.getFromValue(telephonyManager!!.serviceState.state)
```

If it's STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE or STATE_POWER_OFF, it means you are completely disconnected. If you have STATE_EMERGENCY_ONLY, it means you can only call emergency phone calls.

2. You can use `subscriptionManager.activeSubscriptionInfoList` . If you get a non-empty list, I think it means you are connected:

   ```
   fun hasCellConnection(context: Context): Boolean {
       val subscriptionManager = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE) as SubscriptionManager
       val activeSubscriptionInfoList = subscriptionManager.activeSubscriptionInfoList
       return !activeSubscriptionInfoList.isNullOrEmpty()
   }
   ```