# How to check if wifi is connected in uiautomator?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

in my uiautomator test, i want to do something like

```
if( wifi is connected) {
    doSth();
} else {
    doSthElse();
}
```

Can I check that?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009804/check-network-connection-android

Answer (score 1):

Since version 21 (?) UiAutomator has access to Instrumentation and thus to Context.

```
Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
Context context = instrumentation.getContext();
WifiManager wManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); //this works for other services as well
```

Now you can use all WifiManager methods such as:

```
wManager.isWifiEnabled()
wManager.setWifiEnabled(boolean)  //turn wifi on and off
```

Answer (score 0):

**method-1**

Goto Wifi page- check "*Conncted*" string below your ssid.

**method-2**

check out put of `adb shell netcfg` and grep for valid ipaddress for wifi interface,mostly- `wlan0`.

**method-3** (but works on rooted phones)

check out put of `adb shell wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 status`, It gives wifi connected or not information.

All above methods you can code with uiautomator.